# Thread-safe implementation of builder pattern

Tags: java, multithreading, design-patterns

There is an [article](https://jlordiales.wordpress.com/2012/12/13/the-builder-pattern-in-practice/) that I came across while I was looking for a good practice of [builder pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern).

In the article, the author mentions about something that drew my attention. the pattern being thread safe.

The first variation of `build()` method is thread-safe:

```
public User build() {
    User user = new user(this);
    if (user.getAge() > 120) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Age out of range"); // thread-safe
    }
    return user;
}
```

Whereas, this one is not:

```
public User build() {
    if (age > 120) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Age out of range"); // bad, not thread-safe
    }
    // This is the window of opportunity for a second thread to modify the value of age
    return new User(this);
}
```

Although, I think a better approach would be throwing `IllegalStateException` in the setters:

```
public User build() {
    User u = null;
    try {
        u = new User(this);
    }
    catch(IllegalStateException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return u;
}
```

where the constructor looks like this:

```
private User(UserBuilder builder)
{
    setAge(builder.age);
}
```

and the setter is:

```
void setAge(int age) throws IllegalStateException {
    if(age > 0 && age < 120) this.age = age;
    else throw new IllegalStateException("Age out of range");
}
```

would my approach still be thread-safe? If not, why? And what is the best way to implement the builder pattern in a thread-safe way?

Comment: Why is this an issue? Why would two threads be using the *same* builder, at the same time? Or at all?

Comment: Why on earth would one share builders between threads??

Comment: None of this code is thread safe.  The blogger doesn’t know what he's talking about.  To be thread safe, you must use `volatile`, `synchronized`, or one or more classes in java.util.concurrent or its subpackages.

Comment: @SleimanJneidi many threads may try to create a user concurrently, might they not?

Comment: read the original article comments, people there have already discussed this

Comment: The builder-design is suppose to guarantee the item being built is immutable and as a result thread-safe.

Comment: @cagirici No, it doesn't make sense, sharing initialization with multiple threads is not a sensible thing to do. As VGR said, the blogger doesn't know what they talking about.

Comment: @cagirici Sure, many threads may try to create a user concurrently, but they would all be using *different* builder instances. A builder instance doesn't need to be thread-safe, because it will never be used by multiple threads. In general, builders don't even get re-used by the same thread, since a new builder will (generally) be used for each object to be created.

Comment: @zec, Re, "The builder-design is suppose to guarantee the item being built is immutable."  That might depend on who does the supposing.  It would be more accurate to say that the original _intent_ of the builder pattern was to provide a clean way to construct complicated immutable objects.  But if I copied the builder example right out of the GoF book and then just changed one thing---if I made the built object mutable---would I then have to call it something else?

Comment: The question of whether or not something is a "Builder" is completely orthogonal to the question of whether or not something is "thread-safe."  The rules for designing a thread-safe `FooBuilder` class are no different from the rules for designing a thread-safe `AnythingElse` class.  Though, as others have already pointed out, if you think you need a thread-safe builder, then you are doing something _surprising_.    (Google "Principle of least surprise.")

Answer (score 2):

Your proposal is thread safe in the sense that the `User` object returned will have a value in the legal range, which is not guaranteed with the "bad" example.  Your example does return null rather than throwing an exception if the builder had an illegal value, which may or may not be what you want.

One would not normally want to access a builder object from multiple threads.  However, it's always better to use thread safe code when doing so is easy as in this case; I can imagine unusual cases where one actually would want the builder to be populated by multiple threads.  In those cases, of course, access to the builder would need to be properly synchronized, for example through the use of volatile variables.

Answer (score 2):

From my experience there is no easy way to make the builder pattern thread safe assuming it's even possible for most implementations.

The nature of the builder pattern implies that values should be persisted between setup calls, right up to the build method is called and potentially beyond. Thus any thread sharing the builder could potentially change the values before the build method is called resulting in an incorrect result for all threads but the last.

I cannot be sure for your solution what the best approach is but I have successfully implemented builder patterns in a threaded client by introducing a factory to create a new builder every time the builder is needed and only using the builder as a local variable this keeping it on a separate stack.

I have found this to be the simplest, safest and most efficient method.

Remember keep it stupid simple, if you are jumping through hoops like in your example then I would treat this as a smell and consider a new approach.